# Awaiting a list of asynchronous tasks that have polymorphic results

Tags: c#, async-await, polymorphism

The problem I need to solve is that of having different calls that returns tasks, but they may or may not contain the base or some derived class, and then awaiting all those calls before proceeding.

The following, non-working, code illustrates the problem:

```
class Base {

}

class Derived : Base {

}

public void Main() {
    List<Task<Base>> taskList = new List<Task<Base>>();

    for ( var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        switch (i%2) {
            case 0:
                taskList.Add(GetDerivedAsync());
                break;
            default:
                taskList.Add(GetBaseAsync());
                break;
        }
    }

    Task.WhenAll(taskList);
}
```

The above code doesn't work becauase you cant add a `Task<Derived>` to a list of `Task<Base>`.

**How can I make a bunch of asynchronos calls whose returned object is polymorphic in nature, add them to a list and then await all of them before continuing the code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to convert the result of `GetDerivedAsync()` from `Task<Derived>` to `Task<Base>` in order to get them into the same list.

```
public Task<Base> GetBaseTaskFromDerived(Task<Derived> derivedTask)
{
    return await derivedTask;
}
```

Then add like this: `taskList.Add(GetBaseTaskFromDerived(GetDerivedAsync()));`

Answer (score 2):

Do you care about the return value from `GetBaseAsync()` or `GetDerivedAsync()`?

If not you may be able to add them both to a `List<Task>` or `List<Task<object>>` instead of `List<Task<Base>>`.

If you do care about the return value one of your options would be to add an `interface` on `Base` and use that `interface` on your `List<Task<T>>` declaration like below

```
interface IBaseResult {
    string PropertyYouCareAbout1 { get; }
    bool PropertyYouCareAbout2 { get; }
    // ...
    int PropertyYouCareAboutN { get; }
}

class Base : IBaseResult {

}

class Derived : Base {

}

public void Main() {
    List<Task<IBaseResult>> taskList = new List<Task<IBaseResult>>();

    for ( var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        switch (i%2) {
            case 0:
                taskList.Add(GetDerivedAsync());
                break;
            default:
                taskList.Add(GetBaseAsync());
                break;
        }
    }

    Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    // Do somethign with results in taskList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit the fact that [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) derives from `Task`, and store the tasks in a `List<Task>`:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
```

Then awaiting all tasks is easy.

```
await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

The tricky part is how to collect the results of these tasks after the awaiting, into a `List<Base>`. It can be done by casting, but it's neither pretty nor safe. In the example below I used a *switch expression* (C# 8 syntax) to reduce the verbosity of the casting:

```
List<Base> list = taskList.Select(task => task switch
{
    Task<Base> taskBase => taskBase.Result,
    Task<Derived> taskDerived => taskDerived.Result,
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Task<T>` inherits `Task`, so you can use a `List<Task>` to store both of them.

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(GetDerivedTask());
taskList.Add(GetBaseTask());
```

You'll then have to cast the tasks back to their respective types to access the result:

```
foreach (var task in taskList)
{
    if (task is Task<Base> baseTask)
        ProcessBase(baseTask.Result);            
    else if (task is Task<Derived> derivedTask)
        ProcessDerived(derivedTask.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two lists, one for the base types and one for the derived types:

```
public void Main() {
    var baseTaskList = new List<Task<Base>>();
    var derivedTaskList = new List<Task<Derived>>();

    for ( var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        switch (i%2) {
            case 0:
                derivedTaskList.Add(GetDerivedAsync());
                break;
            default:
                baseTaskList.Add(GetBaseAsync());
                break;
        }
    }

    Task.WhenAll(baseTaskList);
    Task.WhenAll(derivedTaskList);
}
```

This way you don't have to modify your types and you can easily get the results of the tasks.